# Casting to enum type leads to erroneous values in C

Tags: c, casting, c99

I have an enum `my_enum` defined as follows:

```
typedef enum {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C',
} my_enum;
```

Now I am trying to read a value from `stdin` into a variable of type `my_enum`:

```
my_enum data;
scanf("%c", (char*)&data);
```

The interesting thing is that **sometimes**, the value is correctly casted, but sometimes, I random numeric values.

Could you please explain why this happens and how it can be solved? Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that `sizeof(my_enum)` is greater than 1 and the random junk is because `data` has not been initialized.

Comment: You can't do like that, you have to read the character into an actual `char` variable, then cast it to an `int` to set the value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is there any way I can specify the size for an enumerated type?

Comment: In C it's not possible.

Comment: In C variable arguments functions returns value following **implicit types**, that for a `%c` specifier will return an **integer** not a `char`. Enums are by standard defined ad integers wide enough to hold the enumeration values. Casting an `int *` to a `char *` could lead to truncation (`int` is a **signed value**, char signedness depends on the compiler) with strange results. Try simply `scanf("%c", &data);`, this let the compiler work with implict conversions, anyway it will give you an error if conversion isn't possible.

Comment: Could you guys please provide a formal answer to the question so others can find it too? Thanks